# Email Database Results

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I have a firebase database where onCreate Google Cloud Functions calls nodemailer and sends me an email.  It all works fine but now I am trying to also include the data that was added to the database in the email.  I can't get it to work, seemingly because it is not in a text format and I've tried converting to text and that doesn't seem to do it.  What am I doing wrong?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
// For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
 // TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.
const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: gmailEmail,
    pass: gmailPassword,
  },
});

exports.sendWelcomeEmail =      functions.database.ref('/PickupRequests/{pushId}')
.onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {

  const val = snapshot.data;

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '<noreply@firebase.com>',
    to: "mike@puravidalaundry.com",
    subject: "New Pickup Request",
    text: val //How do i convert this to a text format?
  };

  try {
    await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('email sent');
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('There was an error while sending the email:',     error);
  }
  return null;
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

figured it out. I had to create a new variable const newvar = JSON.stringify(val) and then i said text: newvar

Answer (score -1):

To get the value from the snapshot, use `snapshot.val()`. So:

```
const val = snapshot.val();
```

Note that this is shown in an example in the documentation on [handling event data for Realtime Database triggered Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data).

Comment: OK i'm a little further, thank you.  However, now the email just says "[object Object]"

Comment: figured it out.  I had to create a new variable const newvar = JSON.stringify(val) and then i said text: newvar